# iframe Content breaks in IE 9

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am using an iframe to include a list of content. Attached is an image of what I see in IE9 only. The spacing between images and name is off and are overlapping. I have tried multiple ways to fix this. Any ideas or suggestions?

[image]

Comment: share css to help you better

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KNeuP/ Here is the code I am using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using an iframe, this issue was easily solved using a scrolling div! I don't know why I didn't think of this sooner!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like  a simple CSS problem. But can't say much more without knowing what styles are applied in the iframe.

I suppose the 3 columns need to be wrapped in a div with the width set to the correct size, or the iframe needs to be less large. As for the text can't say without knowing more details